# How to sum column of result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a problem, I want to sum the column of my results, this my code:

```
SELECT 
    [study_service]
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_arrivee],[study_date_patient_prepared]) as [Time-ARRIVED-PREPARED]
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_arrivee],[study_date_start]) as [Time-ARRIVED-START] 
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_start],[study_date_dossier_pret]) as [Time-START-DOSSPRET]
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_dossier_pret],[study_date_remise_resultat]) as [Time-DOSSPRET-DOSSREMIS]
FROM 
    [VisionTST].[dbo].[PremierTrimestre]
```

I want the final result like this:

```
Total of `[Time-ARRIVED-PREPARED]`,`[Time-ARRIVED-Start]`,...
```

Comment: Google is your friend. Do you tealise how many `SUM` examplea there are?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  [study_service]
  ,sum(DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_arrivee],[study_date_patient_prepared])) as [Time-ARRIVED-PREPARED]
  ,sum(DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_arrivee],[study_date_start])) as [Time-ARRIVED-START]
  ,sum(DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_start],[study_date_dossier_pret])) as [Time-START-DOSSPRET]
  ,sum(DATEDIFF(minute,[study_date_dossier_pret],[study_date_remise_resultat])) as [Time-DOSSPRET-    DOSSREMIS]

FROM [VisionTST].[dbo].[PremierTrimestre]
```

Comment: IMHO he wants count, not sum. i.e. number of prepared/start/etc occurences, not a "date-sum".

Comment: That could be true, but then he should specify.

Either way if he wants to count, replace the 'sum' with 'count'

Comment: exactely Tarske i want sum not count, i.e the sum of each column.not works man :( i got an error.

Comment: yup, you need GROUP BY for all columns if you sum (or count) values